# celery logs question

Tags: django, django-celery

I'm running django app + django-celery with rabbitmq-server on Ubuntu.
I get a lot of these errors in celery:

> [2011-06-03 13:58:15,387: WARNING/PoolWorker-1] HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

Where can I find the traceback or response of this request to check what's getting wrong?
In which logs should I look?

Thanks, Arshavski Alexander

Comment: what are you using celery to do? Have you got tasks defined?

Comment: Have you tried the `celery_taskmeta` table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you don't launch it not as a daemon but directly by using the python manage.py celeryd command with -l DEBUG option

```
python manage.py celeryd -l DEBUG
```

In this way you are able too see full colorized debug logs on interactive shell.